# Why is this c# constructor not working as expected?

Tags: c#, constructor

I am trying to initialize a constructor differently if it's called with a parameter that meets certain criteria and I have the following code.

```
class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private int _pId;
    private string _message;
    private string _channelPath;

    public MessageEventArgs(string message)
    {
        _pId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        _message = message;
        _channelPath = null;
    }

    public MessageEventArgs(string[] details)
    {
        if (details.Length == 1)
        {
            new MessageEventArgs(details[0]);
            return;
        }
        _pId = int.Parse(details[0]);
        _message = details[1];
        _channelPath = details[2];
    }
}
```

Which surprisingly is not working, on debugging and stepping through line by line, I see everything called properly, but after instantiation, `pId` and `_message` have their default values i.e. 0 and null

Comment: Show the line where you actually create the `MessageEventArgs` instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not invoking the other constructor, you are creating a second instance which you initialize with the default values.

Hence the first instance is still uninitialized.

You need to do it like this:

```
class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private int _pId;
    private string _message;
    private string _channelPath;

    public MessageEventArgs(string message)
    {
        _pId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        _message = message;
        _channelPath = null;
    }

    public MessageEventArgs(string[] details)
    {
        if (details.Length == 1)
        {
            _pId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
            _message = details[0];
            _channelPath = null;
            return;
        }
        _pId = int.Parse(details[0]);
        _message = details[1];
        _channelPath = details[2];
    }
}
```

I would probably check if the details are `null` also..

Answer (score 8):

As per spec, in C#, you cannot call another constructor from a class. So it's not the return statement, but it's the improper attempt to call the other constructor. You have to make an `Initialize` method that embodies what you're trying to do and call it from both methods.

```
class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private int _pId;
    private string _message;
    private string _channelPath;

    public MessageEventArgs(string message)
    {
        Initialize( message );
    }

    public MessageEventArgs(string[] details)
    {
        if (details.Length == 1)
        {
            Initialize( details[ 0 ] );
            return;
        }

        _pId = int.Parse(details[0]);
        _message = details[1];
        _channelPath = details[2];
    }

    private void Initialize(string message)
    {
        _pId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        _message = message;
        _channelPath = null;     
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not overload the constructor? That's what overloading is there for.

Comment: The reason overloading doesn't work in this situation is because you can't call another constructor explicitly from within a class. He's trying to not have two constructors with repeated logic.

Comment: My example below has only one constructor with logic in it, the other is empty. You simply overload the ctor by using ": this(...)"

Comment: But it adds extra overhead by creating a new array, and your solution isn't scalable. Consider if he had another constructor that took two strings. Then three strings. Etc...

Comment: Sure, but the overloading is actually possible

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is any cleaner but you could try the following:

```
    public MessageEventArgs(string message)
        : this(new [] {message})
    {
    }

    public MessageEventArgs(string[] details)
    {
        if (details.Length == 1)
        {
            _pId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
            _message = details[0];
            _channelPath = null;
        }
        else
        {
            _pId = int.Parse(details[0]);
            _message = details[1];
            _channelPath = details[2];
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is how I would do it, but why not `: this( new[] { Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, message, null } )` and avoid the details.Length check entirely?

Comment: Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id is an int so that won't compile. I decided against casting and int to a string and then back to an int as it seemed a bit messy. Went for the length check instead.

Comment: Makes sense, though I personally would just slap on the .ToString(). Preferences and what-not.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return anything from a constructor. Try something like this.

```
    if (details.Length == 1)
    {
        _pId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
         _message = message;
        _channelPath = null;
    }
    else 
    {
        _pId = int.Parse(details[0]);
        _message = details[1];
        _channelPath = details[2];
    }
```

Comment: The return is actually to prevent further execution. That's why I'm wondering if it's wrong.

Comment: I am bit confused, if your statement is correct @jgauffin 's answer should be wrong coz he is obviously returning from constructor.

Comment: He's not trying to return something from the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a constructor of the same class from a constructor. Your code creates a local instance of MessageEventArgs, and it goes out of scope which is why you don't see the expected behavior.

Constructors are meant to create the instance of the object based on the parameters passed. Overloading is meant to allow different parameters to be passed and result in proper instantiation of the object. Constructors are meant to be atomic so that if you remove one constructor it does not impact the others.

Your code should look like this:

```
class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private int _pId;
    private string _message;
    private string _channelPath;

    public MessageEventArgs(string message)
    {
        _pId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        _message = message;
        _channelPath = null;
    }

    public MessageEventArgs(string[] details)
    {
        if (details.Length == 1)
        {
            _pId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
            _message = details[0];
            _channelPath = null;
        }
        else 
        {
            _pId = int.Parse(details[0]);
            _message = details[1];
            _channelPath = details[2];
        }
    }
}
```